# Why does YARN complete but there are errors during the compilation

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, yarn-v2

I am facing this error while compilation of my assets

```
Unexpected token: punc (,) [main.js:30830,11][39m[22m
[10:12:12] Finished 'scripts' after 1.03 min
[10:12:12] Starting 'templates'...
[10:12:12] Finished 'templates' after 534 ms
[10:12:12] 
Finished 'default' after 1.17 min
```

My goal is to catch the error while compiling and stop it.
I tried but did'nt find any way to catch the error.